# How do I find where 'given node is not an Element, the node type is: string' error occurred from stack trace? (react/JS)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing a react app as a practice and I get the following error on several components, however I can't see that it tells me where it comes from?  It doesn't prevent tests (jest/react testing library) passing or indeed build (WIP app is successfully deployed to netlify). Nevertheless, I'd like to track it down if only for understanding:

```
      Error: The given node is not an Element, the node type is: string.
          at getWindowFromNode (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/helpers.js:58:11)
          at hasPointerEvents (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils/misc/hasPointerEvents.js:11:49)
          at click (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:116:63)
          at typeImplementation (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/type/typeImplementation.js:24:36)
          at Object.type (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/type/index.js:27:60)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/src/__tests__/transcribe.test.js:33:15)
          at Promise.then.completed (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:391:28)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at callAsyncCircusFn (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:316:10)
          at _callCircusTest (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:218:40)
          at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
          at _runTest (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:155:3)
          at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:66:9)
          at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:60:9)
          at run (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:25:3)
          at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:170:21)
          at jestAdapter (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:82:19)
          at runTestInternal (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:389:16)
          at runTest (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:475:34)
          at Object.worker (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/node_modules/jest-runner/build/testWorker.js:133:12)
```

Current complete code is [here](https://github.com/ccozens/mol-bio-tools) and live app is [here](https://github.com/ccozens/mol-bio-tools) (again: WIP - I know various links/etc don't work yet).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I actually read that trace it highlights an error in my test:
`at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/learning/Documents/projects/mol-bio-tools/src/__tests__/transcribe.test.js:33:15)`

Turns out I'd managed to use a hybrid of @testing-library/userevent v13.5 and v14 syntax, and there are breaking changes between the 2 versions. Updated to v14, updated syntax, all good.